# Jruby on Rails not deploying to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, jruby

I've spent hours unsuccessfully trying to deploy my app to Heroku, and can't figure out the problem.  I'm running on Windows and using JDK8 Jruby9.0.0.0.  I set up using the instructions found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-jruby#introduction) and deploy a new app using this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git).  The exact commands I'm using are:

```
C:\Users\MyName>Jruby -S rails new MyApp
---
C:\Users\MyName>cd MyApp
---
C:\Users\MyName\MyApp>git init
---
C:\Users\MyName\MyApp>git add .
---
C:\Users\MyName\MyApp>git commit -m "my first commit"
---
C:\Users\MyName\MyApp>heroku create
---
C:\Users\MyName\MyApp>git push heroku master
---
C:\Users\MyName\MyApp>heroku open
```

Unfortunately this provides the following "Applicaton Error" when I try to open the app:

```
2015-11-04T19:28:36.377052+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 27765 -e production`
2015-11-04T19:28:38.105808+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: jruby.exe: No such file or directory
2015-11-04T19:28:38.976959+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-11-04T19:28:38.994372+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-04T19:28:38.995406+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-04T19:28:40.545185+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 14126 -e production`
2015-11-04T19:28:41.946326+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: jruby.exe: No such file or directory
2015-11-04T19:28:42.503828+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-04T19:28:42.496390+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-11-04T19:28:43.384581+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=desolate-lake-2856.herokuapp.com request_id=7d58e322-072a-4e26-bfdf-53ff637ebe97 fwd="86.174.222.227" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-04T19:28:43.638575+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=desolate-lake-2856.herokuapp.com request_id=af171d45-f0ce-4e2e-a0ba-1375cfb90601 fwd="86.174.222.227" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-04T19:28:44.199636+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=desolate-lake-2856.herokuapp.com request_id=b0e25fc6-0497-4a6b-ac71-fde22c700e57 fwd="86.174.222.227" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-04T19:28:44.922656+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=desolate-lake-2856.herokuapp.com request_id=d680200e-e6e2-4132-92fe-fcddf8df77f4 fwd="104.131.28.255" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I've followed instructions found on SO which suggest renaming bin/bundle,rails,rake to remove the '.exe', but this does not work.

Any ideas on what is going wrong here?  Thanks!

---

EDIT:

I should have said that the app cloned in the Heroku tutorial deploys to Heroku as it should, but unfortunately it is completely different in structure to the app created by the CMD command 'Jruby -S rails new MyApp'.  The cloned app has no 'bin' directory, and the 'Jruby -S new' app has no procfile.  I think this means that the problem lies with how the 'Jruby -S new' app is configured to deploy, i.e. I need to specify how the process should start?  Both apps work locally.

I know I could clone the heroku app every time I create a new rails app, but this seems like a bit of a clunky work around!

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have that `.exe` specified anywhere in the directory? Check .ruby-version and Gemfile files

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have your `bin/rails` script checked into Git. And if that script was generated on Windows, I think it will have `jruby.exe` in it. Make sure you remove those files by running:

```
> git rm -rf bin
```

And then add `bin/` to your `.gitignore to make sure it doesn't get back in. Then finally:

```
> git commit -am "remove bin scripts"
> git push heroku master
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried this but ended up with an error saying bin/rails could not be found?  I've edited my description above to give a little more detail about the problem as well.